# Issues getting Java installed in Chrome in Fedora 17 x64

Tags: google-chrome, 64-bit, java, plugins, fedora-17

I am having trouble getting Java to work in Google Chrome on Fedora 17 x64. I have installed the 64-bit RPM from Oracle's site and run `yum install java`, but it doesn't show up in Chrome. Is there something else that I need to do to get this working? It seems to be poorly documented with that browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome does not support 64 bit java that I have found. Sorry. I am forced to use Firefox when working with application that utilize 64 bit java.
[Here](http://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml) is the link of a question asked on Java's website. While it does not list your operating specifically I am very sure it applies to all of them